# MYSQL records not displaying in PHP/HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display MySQL Records in a HTML Table. I have gone through the process and in my php document it displays the tables name, description etc. but the data from my database doesn't display.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

 //establishing connection
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

 //selecting a database
 mysql_select_db('festival');

 $sql="SELECT * FROM deejay";

 $records=mysql_query($sql);

 ?>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <h2>Festival Diagram</h2>
<img src="diagram.jpg" alt="diagram">



<h1>Deejay Data</h1>
<table width="300" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">
 <tr>

<th>dj_id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>country</th>
<th>info</th>

 </tr>
 <?php

 while($deejay=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
  echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" .$records['dj_id']."</td>";
 echo "<td>" .$records['name']."</td>";
 echo "<td>" .$records['country']."</td>"; 
 echo "<td>" .$records['info']."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";

 }
 ?>
</table>



 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do run code here: `$deejay=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)` you are assigning `$deejay` to be the current row item (the next row in the table that you got from `$records`). In other-words `$records` is still the entire retrieved data and `$deejay` is the current row you are on. So you need to say: `$deejay['...']` instead of `$record['...']`.

```
echo "<td>".$deejay['dj_id']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$deejay['name']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$deejay['country']."</td>"; 
echo "<td>".$deejay['info']."</td>";
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have made the adjustments and now it works fine. I am sorry if this was a rookie mistake its only my first week of PHP.

Comment: @user3538195 No problem. As @Varuna Lex mentioned: `mysql` functions are currently deprecated. It would be a better idea to use `mysqli` functions instead (don't worry they work in the same way). As they are also a bit more secure. But for simply learning PHP, using `mysql` is ok.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while($deejay=mysql_fetch_assoc($records)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$deejay['dj_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$deejay['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$deejay['country']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" .$deejay['info']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```